# Find first value not in std::set<int> min-max

Tags: c++, algorithm, set

How do I find the first value `h` that is *not* in `std::set<int> ids` such that result is clamped to `[0, *ids.rbegin() + 1]` range.

I see this is rather simple problem, but I didn't find any matching question yet. Basically I want the inverted set of `ids` so that I can use them.

So far I have following:

```
#incldue <set>
std::set<int> ids;
int h = 0;
for(; !ids.empty() && (h <= *ids.rbegin() + 1); ++h) {
    if(!ids.count(h)) {
        break;
    }
}
// h is now smallest value not in ids.
```

I suspect this be improved further such that e.g the loop is not required?

@edit: to clarify what values are in the set: In my use case the value generated by the algorithm is inserted into the set. I should have really said `std::set<unsigned int>`. I'm happy to so much discussion done on this question!

Comment: With sorted `std::vector`, you would have random access and can check middle element and then check only left or right side. but you cannot access random element from a `std::set`...

Comment: Btw, you can iterate on the `std::set` instead of doing linear look-up.

Comment: Don't you just need `int h = ids.begin() - 1;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Wouldn't that  result in `-1` if `0` was in the set?

Comment: @NathanOliver: this would not detect `3` in a set `{0,1,2,4,5}`

Comment: In most use cases it is best to ignore the holes, and just take the next bigger number. Integers are cheap :).

Comment: @Jarrod42: I already use boost::container::flat_set<> so I have (probably) random access iterators. But since this is potentially generic algorithm as long as the sequence is sorted it should work.

Comment: It's ironic that although there is a balanced binary tree in the implementation of std::set which would allow an O(log N) solution, there is no member function which provides access for any purpose other than finding elements by value. It would be interesting to have an interface like lower_bound which took a function rather than a value, with the understanding that if the function were not monotonically non-decreasing, behaviour would be undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a `std::set`'s elements are sorted, you can use [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

```
std::adjacent_find(set.begin(), set.end(), [](int a, int b){ return a+1 != b; } );
```

This will return an iterator to the first element, `a`, which is **not** followed by the value `a+1`.  Or `set.end()` if there is no such value.

***Sample usage:***

```
std::set<int> ids { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };

// This code assumes a non-empty set, since the range in the question requires same
if ( *ids.begin() > 0 )
{
    // Special case for [0
    std::cout << 0;
}
else
{
    auto res = std::adjacent_find(ids.begin(),
                                  ids.end(),
                                  [](int a, int b){ return a+1 != b; } );
    if ( res == ids.end() )
    {
        // Special case for *ids.rbegin() + 1]
        std::cout << *ids.rbegin() + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Print the value that should have followed this one.
        std::cout << *res + 1;
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
3
```

Comment: Elegant approach.

Comment: Thank you, @StephanLechner.  That particular algo seems to be one that gets _lost in the back of the drawer_ and forgotten.

Comment: For `{1, 2, 3, 5}`, you return `4` instead of `0`.

Comment: @Jarod42 maybe a two step? std::find_if() to check if the set contains zero, then perform this algo, or else return zero

Comment: @Jarod42 you're right -- I misread both the minimum **and** maximum of that range, if `rbegin()+1` is really inclusive.

Comment: From range `[0, *ids.rbegin() + 1]` or simply `[0, ids.size()]`, it is guarantied that `set `has at least one missing number.

Comment: Sample code adjusted to account for the literal edge cases.

Comment: Not sure negative numbers have to be handled, but if it is `{-3, 0, 1, 2, 4}` return -2 instead of `3` (as I understand expectation). And if it is not, your sample is misleading.

Comment: What's the worst case time complexity of `std::adjacent_find`? Is it less than O(n) since that the elements in a `std::set` are ordered?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: `std::adjacent_find` is linear.

Comment: Then what is the advantage of all this added complexity when `std::adjacent_find` is linear? Why not just use a plain and simple for loop, like for example other answers suggest?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli arguably no advantage at all.  This answer was a nice looking one-liner before all the edge cases were observed.

Comment: undefined behavior when set is empty

Comment: @ÖöTiib: *"`// This code assumes a non-empty set`"* Already noted in answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, sorry, I have too long worked under rules that require crash like assert(!ids.empty()); instead of such comments plus undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::set<int> ids;
int h = 0;
for( auto id : ids ) {
    if( id != h )
        break;
     h++;
}
```

Comment: Results with 0 when -1 and 0 are in set.

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` is not optimized for this problem.

Naive approaches both give you O(n) performance and *bad* O(n) performance because you are walking a node based datastructure.

What you want is a sorted "leapable" datastructure (be it some kind of tree, or a skip list) where the size of the leaps is recorded.

Then you can track the delta-id and the size of the leap; if the leap is smaller than the id difference, there is an empty id in there.  If not, there is no empty id in there.

None of the associative containers in std keep track of the information you need, and retrofitting them isn't practical as you are not given access to the "leap" based iteration or structure.

With such a datastructure, insert and remove is O(lgn) as is "find first unused id".  Without it, find first unused id is O(n).

---

That involves some heavy codesmithing.  We can do almost as good, with higher constant costs, by simply storing a set of ranges and wrapping it to guarantee that the ranges don't overlap.

```
struct range {
  int base = 0;
  int length = 0;
  friend bool operator<( range lhs, range rhs ) {
    if (lhs.base != rhs.base) return lhs.base < rhs.base;
    return lhs.length < rhs.length;
  }
  bool operator()(int x) const {
    ERROR( if (length < 0) std::cout << "bad length\n"; )
    ERROR( if (base < 0) std::cout << "bad base\n"; )
    return (x>=base) && (x<(base+length));
  }
};
```

`range` is a half-open interval going from `[base, base+length)`.  Thus `[x,0)` is an empty range for all `x` and `[x,1)` just contains `x`.

It is ordered by `base`.  If you ask for the lower bound of an ordered collection on `[x,0)`

Now we make a `std::set<range>` and wrap it up:

```
struct id_set {
  bool taken(int x) const;
  int find_unused() const;
  void take(int x);
  void recycle(int x);
  int take_unused() {
    auto r = find_unused();
    take(r);
    return r;
  }
  std::size_t count() const {
    std::size_t r = 0;
    for (auto e:state)
      r += e.length;
    ERROR( if (r!=counter) std::cout << "Counter failure\n"; )
    return r;
  }
private:
  std::set<range> state;
  using iterator = std::set<range>::iterator;
  iterator get_interval(int x) const;
  std::size_t counter = 0;
};

id_set::iterator id_set::get_interval(int x) const {
  auto start = state.lower_bound( {x,0} );
  if (start != state.end())
      if ((*start)(x))
        return start;

  if (start == state.begin() )
    return state.end();

  auto prev = std::prev(start);
  if ((*prev)(x))
    return prev;

  return state.end();
}
bool id_set::taken(int x) const {
  return get_interval(x) != state.end();
}

int id_set::find_unused() const {
  auto it = state.begin();
  if (it == state.end()) return 0;
  auto r = it->base + it->length; // we ensure these intervals are never adjacent; thus the element after the first interval is untaken
  ERROR( if (taken(r)) std::cout << "find_unused failed\n"; )
  return r;
}

void id_set::take(int x) {
  if (taken(x)) return; // nothing to do
  ++counter;

  auto merge_with_next = [&](auto next) {
    VERBOSE(std::cout << "merge_with_next\n"; )
    auto tmp = *next;
    tmp.base = x;
    ++tmp.length;
    state.erase(next);
    state.insert(tmp);
    ERROR( if (!taken(x)) std::cout << "merge_with_next failed\n"; )
  };
  auto merge_with_prev = [&](auto prev) {
    VERBOSE(std::cout << "merge_with_prev\n"; )
    auto tmp = *prev;
    ++tmp.length;
    state.erase(prev);
    state.insert(tmp);
    ERROR( if (!taken(x)) std::cout << "merge_with_prev failed\n"; )
  };
  auto merge_prev_and_next = [&](auto prev, auto next) {
    VERBOSE(std::cout << "merge_prev_and_next\n"; )
    auto tmp = *prev;
    tmp.length += next->length + 1;
    state.erase(prev);
    state.erase(next);
    state.insert(tmp);
    ERROR( if (!taken(x)) std::cout << "merge_prev_and_next failed\n"; )
  };
  auto insert_in_gap = [&] {
    VERBOSE(std::cout << "insert_in_gap\n"; )
    state.insert( {x, 1} );
    ERROR( if (!taken(x)) std::cout << "insert_in_gap failed\n"; )
  };

  if (state.empty())
    return insert_in_gap();

  auto start = state.lower_bound( {x,0} );

  // this is before the beginning, and there is a gap:
  if (start == state.begin() && start->base > x+1)
    return insert_in_gap();
  if (start == state.begin()) {
    // no gap and just before start
    return merge_with_next(state.begin());
  }
  // this is valid, because we are not begin:
  auto prev = std::prev(start);
  if (start == state.end() || start->base != x + 1) {
    if (prev->base + prev->length == x)
      return merge_with_prev(prev);

    return insert_in_gap();
  }     
  // both prev and start are valid iterators
  // start->base == x+1
  if (prev->base + prev->length == x)
    return merge_prev_and_next(prev, start);

  return merge_with_next(start);
}
// return an id:
void id_set::recycle(int x) {
  auto it = get_interval(x);
  if (it == state.end()) return; // nothing to do
  --counter;

  // create two intervals, one before and one after:      
  auto lhs = *it;
  lhs.length = x-lhs.base;
  auto rhs = *it;
  rhs.base = x+1;
  rhs.length -= lhs.length+1;
  // remove this interval:
  state.erase(it);
  // insert either non-zero length interval:
  if (lhs.length > 0)
    state.insert(lhs);
  if (rhs.length > 0)
    state.insert(rhs);
  ERROR( if (taken(x)) std::cout << "recycle failed\n"; )
}
```

there are probably typos above.  But the core idea is that `take` and `recycle` are both O(lgn) operations, as is `find_unused`.  Thus `take_unused` is also O(lgn).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/667f68b92a1450cb)

Answer (score 0):

Your version is `O(n log(n))`.
You can have it in linear time (`O(n)`):

```
int h = 0;
for (const int e : ids) {
    if (e != h) {
        return h;
    }
    ++h;
}
return h;
```

If `ids` can contains negative numbers, then change the loop to:

```
int h = 0;
for (auto it = ids.lower_bound(0); it != ids.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it != h) {
        return h;
    }
    ++h;
}
return h;
```

With sorted vector, you can even reduce complexity to `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the set are sorted. Hence, when you iterate the elements, you just have to detect the first "leak" (e.g. if the value of the set is larger than a linear increasing integral value). You can define where to start, e.g. you could write `h=1` if you want to ignore value `0`, and also the corner case of a set of continuous numbers is covered (result is then max+1):

```
int main() {
    std::set<int> mySet = {5,4,6,2,1,0};
    int h=0;
    for(auto val : mySet) {
        if (val != h) {
            break;
        }
        h++;
    }

    cout << "not in mySet:" << h << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `std::set` to store a set of integers, then unfortunately linear traversal (suggested in other answers) is the best option.

With a small modification to your search tree you can achieve `O(log n)` search for the smallest missing integer while retaining all the other properties - you just need to store the amount of entries smaller than the key for each tree node. Not sure whether you can implement it without rewriting the whole `std::set` though.
UPD: turns out you can - check the answer by @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont

In fact, by caching the smallest value after each operation on your container, you can get it to "find" your number in `O(1)`, which is asymptotically unbeatable. Of course, it will not gain you any actual performance improvement.

Finally, if there are any additional limitations placed upon your integers, you can sometimes come up with some clever trick (usually happens in coding tasks from the training websites) - e.g. if you know that there is exactly one number missing in a range, you can calculate it arithmetically in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I already accepted @Drew Dormann's answer. However I modified the algo such that I can to allow inserting the values into `std::list<int>` keeping the list sorted.
I also made it a generic template function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
// Make smallest sequential val that is not in c.
// returns [val, *c.rbegin() + 1] and suitable iterator to insert val into c.
template<typename Cont>
void make_minimal_id(const Cont & c, typename Cont::value_type & val,
                     typename Cont::const_iterator & x)
{
    if( c.empty()) {
        x = c.begin();
    } else if ( *c.begin() > val ) {
        x = c.begin();
        val = *x - 1;
    } else {
        // "one algo that gets lost in the back of the drawer and forgotten."
        x = std::adjacent_find(c.begin(), c.end(),
            [](typename Cont::value_type a, typename Cont::value_type b)
            { return a + 1 != b; } );
        if ( x == c.end() ) {
            val = *c.rbegin() + 1;
        } else {
            val = *x++ + 1;
        }
    }
}
// pretty print container 
template<typename C>
void print_cont(const C & c) {
    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::next(c.begin()), c.end(),
        std::to_string(c.front()), // start with first element
        [](std::string a, int b) {
            return a + ", " + std::to_string(b); }) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::list<unsigned int> ids = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 };
    print_cont(ids);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        unsigned int id = 0;
        std::list<unsigned int>::iterator x;
        make_minimal_id(ids, id, x);
        ids.insert(x, id);
        print_cont(ids);
    }
    // prints:
    //{3, 4, 5, 6, 9}
    //{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}
    //{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}
    //{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}
    //{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}
    //{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    //{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    return 0;
}
```

`make_minimal_id()` now works for any sorted container and value. :-)